# method cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, methods, parameters

In my program, I'm trying to call the `throwDice` method in a different class.

```
public class SimpleDice {  
  private int diceCount;

  public SimpleDice(int the_diceCount){
    diceCount = the_diceCount;
  }

  public int tossDie(){
    return (1 + (int)(Math.random()*6));
  }

  public int throwDice(int diceCount){
           int score = 0;
           for(int j = 0; j <= diceCount; j++){
            score = (score + tossDie());
           }
           return score; 
         }
}

import java.util.*; 

public class DiceTester {
public static void main(String[] args){

  int diceCount;
  int diceScore;

    SimpleDice d = new SimpleDice(diceCount);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of dice.");
    diceCount = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter target value.");
    diceScore = scan.nextInt();

    int scoreCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
     d.throwDice();
      if(d.throwDice() == diceScore){
        scoreCount += 1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Your result is: " + (scoreCount/100000));
}
}
```

When I compile it, an error pops up for the `d.throwdice()` and says it can't be applied. It says it needs an int and there are no arguments. But I called an int `diceCount` in the `throwDice` method, so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Incidentally, `throwDice` throws the dice `diceCount + 1` times because the `for` loop's condition is `j <= diceCount`.  It will throw the dice for `j` from `0` through `diceCount`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
 d.throwDice();
  if(d.throwDice() == diceScore){
    scoreCount += 1;
  }
}
```

There are two things wrong with this code:

1. It calls `throwDice` without an `int` (you have defined it as `public int throwDice(int diceCount)`, so you must give it an `int`)
2. It calls `throwDice` twice each loop

You could fix it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
 int diceResult = d.throwDice(diceCount); // call it with your "diceCount"
                                          // variable
  if(diceResult == diceScore){ // don't call "throwDice()" again here
    scoreCount += 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`throwDice()` does require you to pass an int as the parameter:

```
public int throwDice(int diceCount){..}
```

And you are providing no arguments:

```
d.throwDice();
```

You need to pass an int as the parameter in order to make this work:

```
int n = 5;
d.throwDice(n);
```

The variable `diceCount` on the method declaration of `throwDice(int diceCount)` only indicates it requires an `int` as an argument and that the argument will be stored in the variable `diceCount`, it doesn't actually provide the actual primitive `int`.

Finally, you are also calling  `throwDice` twice.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `throwDice` as taking an `int` as follows:

```
public int throwDice(int diceCount)
```

But you are calling it without any args which just won't work:

```
d.throwDice();
```