# Passing header and body to post request

Tags: java, post, request, header, response

I am trying to pass header and body to a post request in the second method with the following code but I am getting these errors for the last two lines of the second method

```
'header(java.lang.String)' in 'io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
'body()' in 'io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'
```

```
public static Response Creds(String url){
        RequestSpecification httpRequest=RestAssured.given()
                .auth().oauth2(Authentication.login("user","password"));

        Response response = httpRequest.get(url);
        ResponseBody body=response.getBody();
        body.prettyPrint();
        return response;
    }

 public static void CreateActivityPost(){

        Response response=Authentication.Creds("www.randomurl.com");
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        requestParams.put("userId", "TQ123");
        requestParams.put("isbn", "9781449325862");
        response.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        response.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
        
    }
```

How can I make the post request work with the body and header ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [method cannot be applied to given types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599595/method-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Comment: I wouldn't know how to apply it to my code or if sending the body and header in the post request would even work after.